# Python parallel list processing not working like expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, parallel-processing, iterator

I am using this library for parallel list processing: https://github.com/npryce/python-parallelize (Java fork-join like implementation)

This code works like expected

```py
func = lambda x: x is not None
for i in parallelize([1, None, "3", "zsh"]):
    if func(i):
        print(i)
# Output: 1, "3", "zsh"
```

while this doesn't work:

```py
func = lambda x: x is not None
src = []
for i in parallelize([1, None, "3", "zsh"]):
    if func(i):
        src.append(i)
print(src) # Output: []
```

The used library code looks like that:

```py
import sys
from itertools import islice
import os
import multiprocessing


def per_cpu(seq):
    cpu_count = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    return (islice(seq, cpu, None, cpu_count) for cpu in range(cpu_count))


def parallelize(seq, fork=per_cpu):
    pids = []

    for slice in fork(seq):
        pid = os.fork()
        if pid == 0:
            yield from slice
            sys.exit(0)
        else:
            pids.append(pid)

    for pid in pids:
        os.waitpid(pid, 0)
```

**Update:** I tried to use a shared list. It works but multiprocessing shows an assertion error

```java
    manager = Manager()
    shared_list = manager.list()

    func = lambda x: x is not None
    for i in parallelize([1, None, "3", "zsh"]):
        if func(i):
            shared_list.append(i)
    print(shared_list)
```

The error is:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 147, in join
    assert self._parent_pid == os.getpid(), 'can only join a child process'
AssertionError: can only join a child process
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The *src* list cannot be shared across processes. I would also be very wary of using code that overrides built-in functions

Comment: Suggested experiment: Replace `print(i)` with `print(f"pid = {os.getpid()}", i)` and also get the `pid` of the parent process beforehand (I understand why you're puzzled, it takes a while to get used to it :)).